# Divisibility of (finite) power sum of integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Consider the power sum
$$S_a(b)=1^{2b}+2^{2b}+\cdots+(3a-2)^{2b}.$$
Let $\nu_3(x)$ denote the $3$-adic valuation of $x$.

> **QUESTION 1. (milder)** Is this true?
> $$\nu_3\left(\frac{S_a(b)}{S_a(1)}\right)=0.$$
> **QUESTION 2.** Is this true? $\nu_3(S_a(b))=\nu_3(2a-1)$.

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 are clearly equivalent, since $S_a\left(1\right) = 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + \left(3a-2\right)^2 = \dfrac12 \left(2a-1\right) \left(3a-1\right) \left(3a-2\right)$ has the same $3$-adic valuation as $2a-1$.

Comment: I suspect that your conjecture is indeed true, and in fact that $S_a\left(b\right)$ is a polynomial in $a$ of the form $\dfrac{1}{m} \left(2a-1\right) \left(3 q\left(a\right) + r\right)$, where $q$ is an integral polynomial and where $m$ and $r$ are two integers not divisible by $3$. This should really be a property of Faulhaber polynomials, but I am too *faul* to translate it into that language :) (I have checked it for all $b \leq 8$.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg: interesting. How do you ensure that $m$ and $r$ are not divisible by $3$?

Comment: That's why I'm saying "suspect"...

Comment: Yes, you did say that. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that
$$2S_a(b) \equiv 1^{2b} + 2^{2b} + \dots + (6a-4)^{2b} \pmod{6a-3}.$$

From Faulhaber's formula, we have
$$1^{2b} + 2^{2b} + \dots + (6a-4)^{2b} \equiv B_{2b} (6a-3) \pmod{6a-3}.$$
It follows that
$$S_a(b) \equiv \frac32B_{2b} (2a-1)\pmod{3(2a-1)},$$
where $\nu_3(\frac32 B_{2b})=0$ by [von Staudt–Clausen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem).
Hence, $\nu_3(S_a(b))=\nu_3(2a-1)$.

---

**ADDED.** Explanation of the [Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) implication:

**Lemma.** Let $n,m$ be positive integers, $m$ is even. Then
$$1^{m} + 2^{m} + \dots + (n-1)^{m} \equiv B_{m} n \pmod{n}.$$

**Proof.** For $m=2$, the statement can be verified directly:
$$1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + (n-1)^2 = \frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6} \equiv B_2 n\pmod{n}.$$
For the rest assume $m\geq 4$.

Using Faulhaber's formula and taking into account that $B_{m-1}=0$, we have
\begin{split} 
& 1^{m} + 2^{m} + \dots + (n-1)^{m}  \equiv 1^{m} + 2^{m} + \dots + n^{m} \\
&\equiv B_{m} n + \frac{1}{m+1} \sum_{k=3}^{m+1} \binom{m+1}{k} B_{m+1-k} n^k \pmod{n}.
\end{split}
It remains to show that $\frac{1}{m+1} \binom{m+1}{k} B_{m+1-k} n^k \equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for any integer $k\in [3,m+1]$.

Consider any prime $p\mid n$, and let $t:=\nu_p(n)\geq 1$. Our goal is to show that $\nu_p\big(\frac{1}{m+1} \binom{m+1}{k} B_{m+1-k}\big) + t(k-1) \geq 0$.
It is enough to focus on the case $t=1$, from which the case $t>1$ follows instantly.

Since by von Staudt–Clausen theorem the denominators of Bernoulli numbers are square-free, we need to show that
$$\nu_p\big(\frac{1}{m+1} \binom{m+1}{k}\big)  + k - 2 \geq 0.$$

Noticing that $\nu_p\big(\frac{1}{m+1} \binom{m+1}{k}\big) = \nu_p\big(\frac1k\binom{m}{k-1}\big)\geq -\nu_p(k)$, our goal reduces to showing that
$$k-2-\nu_p(k)\geq 0.$$
For $k=3$ and $k=4$, this inequality is trivial, while for $k\geq 5$ it follows from the bound $\nu_p(k)\leq \log_2(k)$. QED

Comment: Would it be possible to elaborate/expand your 2nd congruence with Faulhaber?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: I've just added an explanation.